# How to copy file in svn repository using SQL query?

Tags: sql, svn

I am trying to copy a file in SVN repository from a local copy to a local folder, using SQL - EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sql_mov

```
DECLARE @from VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @to_move VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @sql_mov VARCHAR(200)
SELECT  @from = '\\MU1QA01\C$\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Documentation\Regression Test Cases\Test Data\Data\DTL_Instruments_Equity\DTL_Instruments_Equity_TC1.txt',
        @to_move = '\\MU1QA01\C$\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Automation\TRSTrade\Data\DTL_Instruments_Equity_TC1.txt' 

SET @sql_mov = 'copy ' + @from + ' ' + @to_move

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sql_mov
```

Output is : The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Disks in Windows are normally C:/ not C$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote (`"\\server\C$\path with spaces"`) those network paths:

```
DECLARE @from VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @to_move VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @sql_mov VARCHAR(200)
SELECT  @from = '"\\MU1QA01\C$\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Documentation\Regression Test Cases\Test Data\Data\DTL_Instruments_Equity\DTL_Instruments_Equity_TC1.txt"',
        @to_move = '"\\MU1QA01\C$\Users\sprasad\Desktop\Automation\TRSTrade\Data\DTL_Instruments_Equity_TC1.txt"' 

SET @sql_mov = 'copy ' + @from + ' ' + @to_move

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sql_mov
```